# Верстка блоков, проблема с размещением

Tags: jquery, html, вёрстка, javascript, css

Здраствуйте у меня следущая проблема : есть html код

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">
<title>test</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/js.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="block1" class="block first">
        <p align="center" class="img_bottom"><img src="images/img1.png" alt="img1">
            <p class="zvezda">
                <img src="images/zv.png">
                <img src="images/zv.png">
                <img src="images/zv.png">
                <img src="images/zv.png">
                <img src="images/zv2.jpg">
            </p>
        <p class="hed">New Zealand Timelapse</p>
        <p class="hed1">Equipé de son appareil Canon 5D Mark II, le réalisateur Bevan Percival nous offre une nouvelle vidéo en technique timelapse absolument magnifique</p>
    </div>

    <div id="block2" class="block">
        <p align="center" class="img_bottom"><img src="images/img2.png" alt="img2"></p>
            <p class="zvezda">
                <img src="images/zv.png">
                <img src="images/zv.png">
                <img src="images/zv.png">
                <img src="images/zv2.jpg">
                <img src="images/zv2.jpg">
            </p>
        <p class="hed">New Zealand Timelapse</p>
        <p class="hed1">Equipé de son appareil Canon 5D Mark II, le réalisateur Bevan Percival nous offre une nouvelle vidéo en technique timelapse absolument magnifique</p>
    </div>

    <div id="block3" class="block">
        <p align="center" class="img_bottom"><img src="images/img3.png" alt="img3"></p>
             <p class="zvezda">
                <img src="images/zv.png">
                <img src="images/zv.png">
                <img src="images/zv2.jpg">
                <img src="images/zv2.jpg">
                <img src="images/zv2.jpg">
            </p>
        <p class="hed" class="hed">New Zealand Timelapse</p>
        <p class="hed1">Equipé de son appareil Canon 5D Mark II, le réalisateur Bevan Percival nous offre une nouvelle vidéo en technique timelapse absolument magnifique</p>
    </div>
    <div class="cl"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**СSS:**

```
@charset "windows-1251";
/* CSS Document */

body{
    background-image:url(images/bg.png); 
    background-attachment:fixed; 
    background-repeat:no-repeat; 
    background-position:center center;
    background-size:cover;
    }

#wrapper{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    padding:0 ;
    margin-top: 33.3%;
    margin-bottom: 33.3%;
    }

.block{
    width: 25%;
    height:300px;
    float:left;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    min-width:190px;
    }

.block1.first{
    width: 25%;  
}

@media screen and ( max-width:580px ){ 
 .block,
 .block.first{
    width: 50%;  
 }

 #block3{
    width: 100%;
 }

}

@media screen and ( max-width:390px ){ 
 .block,
 .block.first{
    width: 100%;  
 }

}

@media screen and (max-width:1199px){
    img{
        border-radius:15px;
        }
    }

#block1{
    margin-left: 8.3%;

}

#block2{
    margin-left: 4.2%;
    margin-right: 4.2%;
    }

#block3{
    margin-right: 8.3%;
    }

.hed{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:10px;
    color:#333333;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    text-align:center;
    margin-top:0; 
    padding-top:5px; 
    margin-bottom:0; 
    padding-bottom:0;
    }

.hed1{
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #a1a1a1;
    text-align: justify;
    word-spacing: 4px;
    padding-left: 10%;
    padding-right: 10%;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding-top: 2%;
    padding-bottom: 5%;
    }
.img_bottom{
    margin-bottom:0;
    padding-left: 10%;
    padding-right: 10%;
    }

.zvezda{
    padding-left:40%; 
    padding-right:40%; 
    padding-top:10px; 
    margin:0; 
    padding-bottom:0;
    }

img {
    max-width: 100%;    
}

.cl{
  clear: both;
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    /*$(window).resize(function(){
        $("#block1").css({
            'margin-left':'0'
            }); 
        $("#block2").css({
            'margin-left':'0',
            'margin-right':'0'
            });
        $("#block3").css({
            'margin-right':'0'
            });
        }); 
//конец window*/

});//конец ready
```

Проблема состоит в том, что когда изменяется размер окна меньше 580рх мне нужно чтобы  margin (которые прописаны в javascript) принемали значения 0, в коде написаном выше всё так и работает НО когда я опять растягиваю окно к размеру больше 580рх у них не появляются  margin , которые заданы в сss.

Прошу прощения за дурацкий вопрос но может кто поможет? Очень нужно ..... Я пробовал через условия задать но не выходит ничего......
Вот условия:

```
if(window.outerWidth>"580"){
     $("#block1").css({
            'margin-left':'8.3%'
            }); 
        $("#block2").css({
            'margin-left':'4.2%',
            'margin-right':'4.2%'
            });
        $("#block3").css({
            'margin-right':'8.3%'
            });

     }
    else{
        $("#block1").css({
            'margin-left':'0'
            }); 
        $("#block2").css({
            'margin-left':'0',
            'margin-right':'0'
            });
        $("#block3").css({
            'margin-right':'0'
            });

        }

});//конец ready
```

Comment: спасибо всем кто просмотрел мою проблем но я ее уже решил  через $(window).width()

Comment: @Vitaliisss Ты прям zvezda.немецком

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего css в этом моменте игнорируется (не целиком), так как этот стиль применим только на этой странице, а есть еще общий, параметры которого "перекрывают" данный. Почитайте про атрибут !important. И на будущее: использовать свой css на каждой странице в большинстве случае не логично и не эффективно.